# How do a place the camera first position

Tags: aframe

I am searching . I can a set the first **position** of my camera in A-Frame. I am looking for how to set the first view of the camera.

Answer (score 2):

If by "view" you mean the angle the camera is pointed, you can do this by setting the `rotation` attribute on the parent of the `<a-camera>` entity. Example:

`<a-entity position="0 0 5" rotation="0 90 0">
    <a-camera></a-camera>
</a-entity>`

By rotating 90 degrees on the y-axis, the camera is pointed to the left of the scene (0 degrees would be facing front).

Comment: This answer is passable for orthogonal rotations but it changes the cameras local axis which can give weird results when the an initial non 90 degree rotation is used