# Shift A-Frame Origin

Tags: aframe

When I place a block at the origin it is very far back from my sensors. I wish to move the aframe origin forward 1 meter (1 in the -z direction). Additionally I am using a component which tracks the cameras position and so I cannot just wrap everything in an `<a-entity>` and move that forward. How can I change the position of the origin?

Component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('info-panel', {
  tick: function() {
    var el = this.el;
    var camera = document.querySelector('a-camera');
    var cpos = camera.getAttribute('position');
    var x = cpos.x;
    var z = cpos.z;
    var angle;
    if (z === 0) {
      if (x === 0) {
        angle = 0;
      } else if (x > 0) {
        angle = 90;
      } else {
        angle = -90;
      }
    } else {
      angle = (z > 0 ? 0 : 180);
      angle += 180 / Math.PI * Math.atan(x / z);
    }
    el.setAttribute('rotation', {x: 0, y: angle, z: 0});
  }
});
```

Scene:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-camera></a-camera>
    <a-panel info-panel></a-panel>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can position the camera with wrapper entity.

[How do a place the camera first position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812824/how-do-a-place-the-camera-first-position)

```
<a-entity position="0 0 5">
  <a-camera></a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: It's much simpler then my option, although I don't like wrapping the camera in any entity, for when i need to reposition the camera, or the cameraWrapper, (like to another area for example), I tend to get into unexpected offsets created by people walking around in vive. Is there any significant performance hit when repositioning entire scenes vs the camera only ?

Comment: It does cause a bit more thinking (e.g., with the `camera.userHeight`), but it should be doable. It's becoming best practice to have a `camera rig` to hold both camera and controllers so they move together. If you do something like teleport, you just change the wrapper position. What offsets are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is such functionality,
I would wrap everything except the camera in `<a-entity>`
So You can position 'everything' except the camera.